# AJAX - Show a <div> on a button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, symfony

As I am implementing **AJAX**, I would like this whole `<div>` to show up **as a consequence of clicking the button** in the script below :

```
<div class="col-12" id="deleteVote">
    <div class="row mb-2" >
        <div class="col-12">
            {% for vote in proposal.votes %}
                {% if app.user == vote.user %}
                    <a href="{{ path('vote_delete',{'slug' : slug, 'proposal' : proposal.id, 'vote' : vote.id}) }}" class="btn btn-light ml-1 btn-sm deleteVote" data-toggle="deleteConfirmation">
                        <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> {{ 'vote-delete' | trans }}
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script, I don't really know why the `.show` is not working :

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.votedFullAgreement', function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('vote_add', {'slug' : slug, 'proposal' : proposal.id, 'userVote' : 'votedFullAgreement', 'user' : app.user.id }) }}',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (){
            $('#deleteVote').show();
        },
        error: function (resultat, statut, erreur) {
            }
        });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Btw the script is probably not optimised at all but it's my first one and it's working and sending data...

Thank you !

**EDIT 2 :**

I don't understand why this `if/else` doesn't work. When there's a vote, the `if` works, the button is there when we come back/reload the page, but when there is no vote yet, the `.show();` doesn't activate the `else` which is in `display:none`.

Is it because as soon as I vote, the `if` becomes true? (and `.show();` needs something previously hidden to display but can't find any...)

```
{# Standard loop #}
{% if proposal.votedByUser(app.user) %}
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-12">
                {% for vote in proposal.votes %}
                    {% if app.user == vote.user %}
                            <a href="{{ path('vote_delete',{'slug' : slug, 'proposal' : proposal.id, 'vote' : vote.id}) }}" class="btn btn-light ml-1 btn-sm" data-toggle="deleteConfirmation">
                                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> {{ 'vote-delete' | trans }}
                            </a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
{# AJAX loop #}
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-12">
                {% for vote in proposal.votes %}
                    {% if app.user == vote.user %}
                        {# ID deleteVote here, which has display:none in the CSS #}
                        <a href="{{ path('vote_delete',{'slug' : slug, 'proposal' : proposal.id, 'vote' : vote.id}) }}"  id="deleteVote" class="btn btn-light ml-1 btn-sm" data-toggle="deleteConfirmation">
                            <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> {{ 'vote-delete' | trans }}
                        </a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

**If I split both loops, the AJAX one works only when there is already a vote registered (and the button of the standard loop is already there)**

Comment: Are you sure `$('#deleteVote').show();` is even being executed? Try adding `console.log('showing...');` just before `$('#deleteVote').show();`.

Comment: where is the `class="votedFullAgreement"` in your HTML that you target in your onClick?

Comment: How about notifying if there's any error? `error: (_, ...errors) => console.error(...errors)`

Comment: Can you tell us if that HTML is already on your page or is it loaded on AJAX? If so, you have to use delegation.

Comment: @Skuti OP is already using delegation

Comment: @RockySims I have just tried with a `console.log` in the "success" and yes it gets displayed in the console...

@retrovertigo The "vote" button is inside a `{% if/else %}` block and this `#deleteVote` block is right after the `{% endif %}` but it should not be related...

@Phil I have added a `console.log` in the "error" but the click works and triggers the "success" as stated above

@Skuti Yes that HTML and script are on the same page. The script is at the end of the twig, I don't know if I should add `{% block javascripts %}` though

Comment: I have added a `display: none` to the `<div>` and it works when I click on the button, but I don't want to use that method because it then **only** appears on a click... The thing is : the `<div>` needs to be displayed as soon as there is a vote, and then **as long as this vote exists**, even if we leave the page and come back on it

Comment: How do you know if the vote exists? What does the code for getting that boolean look like?

Comment: Do you have a method for remembering the user's vote (even if user goes to another page and comes back) pick out yet? API call to server I'm guessing?

Comment: The user's vote gets remembered, as on the previous page it still displays what the user has voted, and if we come back on the voting page, the "delete vote" button appears. Wait let me edit the original post to add some code

Comment: I think I just can't use ``display:none`` by default for the ``div``, because I want to see it as long as there is a vote, not just at the very moment I vote...  It might just be an algorithmic issue or even logic but it's getting too complex for me after all these tests... Is there any disable/enable property maybe? So that it gets enabled on the click and then remains as long as needed?